# No module named Scimage in Pycharm when following tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm following this tutorial using windows 10 and pycharm

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial

Below is my code so far

As suggested, I installed scimage using `pip install scikit-image`
Because `pip install scimage` doesnt work and tells me to install `scikit-image`

This worked for installing tensorflow, so I know its installing in the correct directory, but it wont run because it wont recognize `import scimage`

Why wont it recognize this? Am I supposed to import something different?

I tried `import scikit-image as scimage` it didn't find it either.

```
# Import `tensorflow`
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import scimage

# Initialize two constants
x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])

# Multiply
result = tf.multiply(x1, x2)

# Print the result
print(result)


def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory)
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f)
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "C:\\Users\\dm\\PycharmProjects\\test"
train_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Testing")
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? Remember if python3, you need to `pip3 install`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
import skimage
```

Comment: thanks, these tutorials never list the full code so I have to guess what I need to import

Comment: No problem, did that fix it? If so, could you accept as answer so others know.